# Validate only visible tabs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

I am setting three tabs of a website visible or invisible using a VB.NET IF statement.

I need a way to ensure that JavaScript validation code for the controls on these tabs is executed only when the tabs are visible. I imagine that the validation (a tangle of if statements) must go into another if.

Something like

```
if (code here to check whether tabs are visible) {
    if { validation takes place here }
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can use JavaScript to check whether my tabs are visible?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about .NET. So I will assume a few things with this solution including that you are using jquery:

```
$('.tab:visible').each(function(index, tab){
   // run vals on $(tab) or tab
});
```

Or if you were already in a loop for each tab:

```
if($(tab).is(':visible')){
 // validate(tab)
}
```

------ without jQuery ------

Lets assume you add the class `hidden` to a tab in order to hide it. The html (simplified) could look like this:

```
<body>
  <div class='tab'>Hello</div>
  <div class='tab'>World</div>
  <div class='tab hidden'>Mind Blown</div>
</body>
```

Then the JS:

```
var tab, tabs, _i, _len;

// Get an array of elements with class `tab`
tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

// Loop through the array of tabs and assign `tab` to be current tab
for (_i = 0, _len = tabs.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  tab = tabs[_i];
  // Check if `tab` has the class `hidden` in which case we will NOT perform our check
  if (tab.className.indexOf('hidden') === -1) {
    // Perform the check
    console.log('do check');
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3604558 it would be handy if you'd post at least part of your html and javascript, but since you haven't, I will make another assumption: You assign a class to tabs to hide them `.hidden`. I will add this to the answer.